# Find the reflection $f(x)$ and the invers reflection of$ f(x)$

Tags: reflection

With the given reflection 
\begin{align}
f(7x-5)=2x-1
\end{align}
How would I find this reflection, any orientation would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you propose to start tackling this?

Comment: Give some different but suitable values for x, that's how I was thinking of starting it

Comment: Does letting $y=7x-5$ and analyzing with respect to $y$ facilitate?  Or how does letting $g(x)=f(7x-5)$ help a bit here?  Writing down your ideas and adding them to your post might help you and might induce others to help you further.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I'm really stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: $ u = 7x-5 \implies f(u) = 2\left(\dfrac{u+5}{7}\right) - 1 = \dfrac{2u+10}{7} - 1= \dfrac{2u+3}{7}\implies f(x) = \dfrac{2x+3}{7}$. To find the inverse, switch $x$ and $y$ in the last equation we have: $x = \dfrac{2y+3}{7} \implies y = \dfrac{7x-3}{2} = f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: I kept analyzing this but I can't quite get it, I've just started learning functions so a more beginner friendly explanation would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, I misinterpreted the actual problem here, this was actually very easy to understand, thanks anyway!